# Passing Parameters through report pages - Google Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, parameters, parameter-passing, looker-studio

**I am trying to send parameters from one page to another in the google data studio report.**
The parameter getting his values from the user by choosing values in the Drop-down list control on page 1.
And on page 2 I want to filter the data (graphs/bars/tables) by the values in the parameter from page 1.

What is the best way to do so?
How do I send those values as parameter from page to page?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should include what you already tried in your question :).

Answer (score 0):

You can make filters or controls report level. See [the Help center article](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066#filter-inheritance) for specific instructions.